# BOLT: Not able to set 404 page

Tags: bolt-cms

In BOLT `config.yml` file I have set the

`notfound: index.php`

So that every not found exception takes user to the homepage but for some reason it's not working for me. e.g: http://meubleshouse.com/some-invalid-url

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it works, since it expects either:

- The name of a `.twig` file from your theme folder
- Or you'll want to create a 'page' called something like '404 not found', and then put it in config as `notfound: page/404-not-found`.

Comment: I have tried putting `pages` and `pages.twig` both but still no luck.

Comment: I have created a new 404 page `http://meubleshouse.com/page/404-not-found`  and updated the config file as `notfound: page/404-not-found` but still no luck.